# Django get user data in main template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to check if user logged in in the main template using this:

```
{%if request.user%}
   ...
{%endif%}
```

but it's not working maybe because main template doesn't have a view
could any one help i don't know if the question duplicated,but i didn't find my answer.

Comment: `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`. The user is passed to the template, so no need for `request.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Link to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users). this should always be your first point of reference.